# Learning Makefile: Are the rules universal across all implementations of Make?

Tags: cmake, makefile, gnu-make, nmake

I'm interested in learning the art of Makefile projects. However, I have one concern.

For background:
On my computer, I have `nmake` installed, which I'm assuming came with Visual Studio when I installed it. I am possibly thinking of having my C++ projects use the makefile structure using `nmake`. But what if I wanted to move to other popular versions of make? `gmake`? This leads me to my main question:

**If I learned one implementation of `make` (`nmake`, `gmake`) and moved to another, to what extent can I expect a difference in `makefile` syntax? In conventions/practices?**

If there is a substantial difference between each implementation, I have a followup question (a bit opinionated):

**Which implementation of `make` should I learn first and why?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmake is not an implementation of make at all.  It's a completely different tool: cmake is a tool that *creates* project build control files, such as makefiles, Visual Studio project files, Xcode project files, Eclipse project files, etc.  Cmake syntax has no relationship whatsoever to make syntax.

nmake is a "sort of" make tool, but it's also different than other versions of make; most other versions of make (GNU make, Solaris make, BSD make, etc.) conform at least to the POSIX specification for make.  nmake (as far as I'm aware) doesn't do that.  However the basic syntax of nmake for defining rules is similar to other versions of make.

GNU make is a highly portable version of make that supports POSIX, plus a large number of non-portable extensions.  However, GNU make itself is highly portable: in addition to Windows (both native and cygwin) and UNIX (BSD, Linux, Solaris, etc.) systems, it also supports VMS and other operating systems.

Of the above, nmake is the *least* portable option; it's available only on Windows.  cmake is a good choice if you want to use a variety of development tools, but it is not in any way make-like.  If you want to learn make and makefiles and be portable across a wide variety of platforms, your best bet is GNU make.

Comment: You omitted a fact from your description of GNU make - it has extensions versus POSIX make, some of which will interfere with using other versions of make.  The best answer would be to study POSIX make, and learn the differences as needed.

Comment: I did say GNU make has _a large number of non-portable extensions_.  I agree that learning POSIX standard makefiles is the best first step, but I have my doubts that any moderately complicated makefile should be written in plain POSIX make; the capabilities are too annoyingly limited.  If people want to write significant makefiles they should either switch to something like automake (or cmake or whatever), or else choose a portable make like GNU make and feel free to rely on its non-portable extensions.  Anyway, that's MHO.

Comment: You should explain it clearly, then, rather than attempting to be be both vague and self-promotional.

Comment: I'm not sure what's not clear about my response: I said, explicitly, that GNU make supports POSIX and has a lot of non-portable extensions... what would you want me to say that would be less vague?  I'm certainly not going to list all of them!  As for _self-promotional_, I'm not even going to respond to that.  Hopefully you're just having a bad day.